# Constraint on variables in summation

Tags: series-expansion, summation

Is it possible to have a constraint on variables in summation of series just similar to pattern constraint
e.g.

```
Sum[Binomial[i + 3, 3]*Binomial[2, j], {i, 0, Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity} ]
```

with the condition that `i + j = 2`?

Comment: Can't you use the condition to remove the sum over `j` ?

Answer (score 4):

Compare :

```
Sum[Binomial[i + 3, 3]*Binomial[2, j] Boole[i + j == 2], {i, 0, Infinity}, {j, 0, Infinity}]
(* 19 *)
```

and

```
pairs = Solve[{i + j == 2, i >= 0, j >= 0}, {i, j}, Integers]
(* {{i -> 0, j -> 2}, {i -> 1, j -> 1}, {i -> 2, j -> 0}} *)

Total[Binomial[i + 3, 3]*Binomial[2, j] /. pairs]
(* 19 *)
```