# Constrained Sum evaluation

Tags: summation, assumptions

I need to sum up F[x1,x2,...] over x1,x2,... where I have a constraint: x1+x2+...=n (n=positive integer number). For example, I have F[x1,x2] and x1+x2=3, so for the sum I get F[3,0] + F[2,1] + F[1,2] + F[0,3].

I can use, for example, this straightforward code

f[x_, y_, n_] := If[x + y == n, g[x, y], 0]; 
Sum[f[x, y, 3], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}].

But for actual numbers and functions it's not very efficient. Could you suggest a better way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Boole` to keep out the terms of the summation you don't want

```
Sum[F[x1, x2] Boole[x1 + x2 == 3], {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}]
(* F[0, 3] + F[1, 2] + F[2, 1] + F[3, 0] *)
```

Edit:
Or [figure out the list of values beforehand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33642/9490) and sum over that list

```
pairs = Solve[{i + j == 5, i >= 0, j >= 0}, {i, j}, Integers]
(* {{i -> 0, j -> 5}, {i -> 1, j -> 4}, {i -> 2, 
  j -> 3}, {i -> 3, j -> 2}, {i -> 4, j -> 1}, {i -> 5, j -> 0}} *)

Total[F[i, j] /. pairs]
(* F[0, 5] + F[1, 4] + F[2, 3] + F[3, 2] + F[4, 1] + F[5, 0] *)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it is almost the same method, because the number of terms in the sum is the same, so it will probably take almost the same amount of time. For me it interesting whether it is possible to reduce the number of terms in the sum, so to reduce the time needed to evaluate it.

Comment: @Artem, I've edited it now so that it only sums over the pairs that satisfy the constraint - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need!